# php escape method , php curl picture upload

Tags: php, curl, escaping

I'm trying to upload some pictures using php cURL but the issue is that the names of the pictures are very weird . Basically they contain #$% signs like this

```
!Bw5kO2w!mk~$(KGrHqQOKjwEvqEtNICrBMLHRIcc+!~~_1.JPG
```

The picture name is retrieved dynamically so I don't know how to escape the characters.

```
 $image = "@".$imageDirectory.$picture[$picture_no];
```

The error that I'm getting is :

```
:0 cURL error: failed creating formpost data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using urlencode() may help you
http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Do you need to keep the name as it is or you can strip the wrong characters or generate your own name

Comment: and can you provide the full code for the upload and also platform/environement details

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! i finally found that the path to the picture was not correct so that's why curl failed to create the post .